# physic body from png in spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit

i want to make a physicsbody from a .png file.
with some pic´s it works, with some other dont. but all have alpha channel..

is there any problem with my code?

```
SKTexture *shapeTex = [SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shapes"]];
SKSpriteNode *shape = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:shapeTex];
shape.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:shapeTex size:shapeTex.size];
shape.physicsBody.dynamic = 0;
shape.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = 1;
shape.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);
shape.physicsBody.friction = 0.1;
shape.size = self.size;
[self addChild:shape];
```

Comment: you should rather use sktexture textureNamed or skspritenode spritewithimagenamed and remove the uiimage part - that unnecessarily loads the image as uiimage first, rather than just creating a texture directly from the png file. Just maybe that might also fix the problem, maybe.

Comment: thanks. i found out i calculates not the whole .png file but only one shape of it. so i have to make every shape in a single .png file. if anybody knows why that is, please tell, i thought i could build my entire level in PS an then just load it into my game..

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work that way. You may want to look around for a visual editor or use Xcode's built-in Sprite Kit design tool.